# Stop a counter in the background

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

I'm using this script: [CircularCountDownJs](https://github.com/sygmaa/CircularCountDownJs)

I'm using it to create different countdowns on different screens and everything works perfectly except a big problem.

When I start a countdown and let it finish, everything is working, but if I create a 2:00 countdown, move to the next screen, and create another 5:00 countdown, when the 2:00 countdown finishes, it fires the end callback function. I want to avoid this behavior.

I know that the counter is running, although it is not seen on screen. To change the screen to the second counter, the user has to click a `div`, which has a `click` event.

With this click event, I tried to destroy the countdown, but I can only remove the counter from the DOM. The countdown remains working and executes the end function when it arrives at 0.

I need to manually stop the countdown on a user `click` event. I've looked inside the code for days, but I can't figure out how to do it.

I'm using the countdown like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  valor_tiempo_f13 = 10;

  $('#pf-ag-fase1-start').click(function() {
    //empezar programa
    console.log('Programa iniciado');
    // Run the countdown
    $('#quesito').circularCountDown({
      delayToFadeIn: 500,
      size: 160,
      fontColor: '#fff',
      colorCircle: '#2a292f',
      background: '#2a292f',
      reverseLoading: false,
      duration: {
        hours: 0,
        minutes: 0,
        seconds: valor_tiempo_f13
      },
      beforeStart: function() {
      },
      end: function(countdown) {
        countdown.destroy();
        $('.launcher').show();
        $('#facial-antiaging-2-finalizada').addClass('active');
        console.log('Programa terminado');
      }
    });
  });
  
  $('#stop').click(function() {
    console.log('needs to really stop the countdown');
  });
  
});
```

```css
#stop{
  background: #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  bottom: 10%;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.espluga.net/genesis10api/js/circular-countdown.min.js"></script>

<div id="quesito" class="timer"></div>

<div id="pf-ag-fase1-start">START</div>

<div id="stop">STOP</div>
```

Above is the example I need to solve. The STOP button has to destroy the countdown. I have it done graphically, but I can't stop the background process.

Answer (score 0):

If you are insistent on sticking with this counter, you probably have one of two options.

1) Hack the codebase and add a .stop() method or something of that so that you can tie into it and pause or stop an existing counter.

2) Add a flag that gets set on your other click event so you can then check in your "end:" method. Basically it wouldn't keep the "end" method from running, but it would just skip all the logic.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var continue_timer = true;
  valor_tiempo_f13 = 10;

  $('#pf-ag-fase1-start').click(function() {
    //empezar programa
    console.log('Programa iniciado');
    // Run the countdown
    $('#quesito').circularCountDown({
      delayToFadeIn: 500,
      size: 160,
      fontColor: '#fff',
      colorCircle: '#2a292f',
      background: '#2a292f',
      reverseLoading: false,
      duration: {
        hours: 0,
        minutes: 0,
        seconds: valor_tiempo_f13
      },
      beforeStart: function() {
      },
      end: function(countdown) {
        // continue_timer gets set to "false" when your other timer is created
        if (continue_timer === true) {
            countdown.destroy();
            $('.launcher').show();
            $('#facial-antiaging-2-finalizada').addClass('active');
            console.log('Programa terminado');
        }
      }
    });
  });

  $('#stop').click(function() {
    // set our flag to false so our end method doesn't do anything.
    continue_timer = false;
    // Hide the initial timer or whatever you want to do
    $('#quesito').hide();
    console.log('needs to really stop the countdown');
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The 2nd solution seems to be working, but after some testing, it's not working at all. The counter seems to be working on the background as a global variable. This code solves the issue if only one counter is running at the same time. If I launch a second counter with different IDs and variables the first countdown is the first countdown affecting at the second. I need to really stop the counter for the second counter can get his own values without being affected but the first. Thanks.